# C# expression (a = b)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying understand this expression in C#:

```
long x = 0;
long a = long.MaxValue;
long b = long.MinValue;
x = (a = b)
```

What's happening here? Can someone explain it to me?

C# operator? x = (a = b)`

Answer (score 3):

The result of an assignment expression (formed by an assignment operator and two operands) is the assigned value. You can simply rewrite as:

```
a = b;
x = a;
```

or

```
a = b;
x = b;
```

Comment: This is correct, but I would phrase it as, "The result of an assignment expression is the assigned value".